# doubles subtracting isn't returning the right number c++

Tags: c++, functional-testing

I'm creating functional tests to my program, but for some reason when I wrote `system1->getValue() - 36.6033` I got a crazy number like `-6.58727e-005`. I've done some debbuging and `system1->getValue()` is returning `36.6032`, but the subtraction isn't resulting in `0.0001`.

Here is the code:

```
void exponentialFunctionalTest(){
    Model* model = new Model("Exponential test");
    System* system1 = new System("System 1", 100);
    System* system2 = new System("System 2", 0);
    Exponential* exponential = new Exponential("Exponential", system1, system2);
        
    model->add(system1);
    model->add(system2);
    model->add(exponential);
    model->run(0, 100, 1);

    assert(abs(system1->getValue() - 36.6032) < 0.0001);
    assert(abs(system2->getValue() - 63.3968) < 0.0001);

    delete model;
}
```

In this program I have two systems, one has a variable value that starts with `100` and the other `0`. Also, I have an exponential flow that will affect both system's values 100 times. The first system is returning `36.6032` at the end, as it should be, but when I try to use the `assert()` function like my teacher taught me, it isn't working, it keeps passing the test that is suppose to fail.

Comment: Floating point numbers aren't exact. They're just an approximation. If you rely on two floating point numbers being exactly the same, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: `-6.58727e-005` is `-0.0000658727` (shift the decimal point to the left 5 digits). This rounds to `-0.0001`, so it fits your data up to the precision with which you reported it. (A `double` will not store `36.6032` exactly.) So looks like a correct result to me.